# Hacking MV Logs for Change Data Capture

Tags: oracle

I am considering a solution that uses Materialized View Logs in a way that was not intended by Oracle.
The idea is to implement fast refresh MV capability for Oracle source and non-Oracle target.
I have tested this approach to confirm that it works but I am concerned about long-term consequences of this unintended and unsupported usage.

MY_TAB is the Oracle (11.2) table that I want to mirror in another non-Oracle RDBMS.

The refersh of the target table is applied by an external process invoked by Oracle procedure in the source database.
That process accepts the data set extracted from the MV Log, and applies changes to the target.
Upon successful execution processed changes are deleted from the MV Log.

MLOG$_MY_TAB is the MV Log for MY_TAB created as:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON my_tab
WITH PRIMARY KEY;
```

Note: There will be no MV associated with this MV Log.

The referesh process is invoked by calling the following procedure:

```
BEGIN

  SELECT *
  FROM mlog$_my_tab;

  /* Call externall process and pass the data */

  DELETE mlog$_my_tab;

  COMMIT;

END;
```

Does anyone see any specific issues with this approach, other than the general unintended/unsupported concerns?

Comment: You will have to take care of the following points. Deleting the materialized view log might be time consuming depending upon the volume of data in the log. Truncating the log would be a better option. When you are running this process you will have to ensure that there are no transactions happening on the my_tab table. Here is some documentation on the topic of truncating the mview log. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28327/rarmanmv.htm#i30379

Comment: Thank you phonetic_man. I have not seen this doc before, and I am glad deletes from MV Logs are actually covered in Oracle documentation. Makes me feel more confident. I chose DELETE precisely so I don't have to worry about concurrent changes to the base table. I would rather do periodic storage maintenance. Do you agree that with this approach I am protected from deleting unprocessed logs?

Comment: I foresee one issue here. I assume your transaction isolation level is read committed (which is the default). This will guarantee that  "Each query executed by a transaction sees only data that was committed before the query (not the transaction) began.". However, it does not guard you against phantom reads "A transaction re-runs a query returning a set of rows that satisfies a search condition and finds that another committed transaction has inserted additional rows that satisfy the condition." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm. ...continued below...

Comment: So in your case if any additional data is inserted in the MV Log between execution of the SELECT statement and the DELETE statement would be deleted from the mv_log (which is not desirable). You can read the following documentation for complete details. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm

Comment: I wasn't sure whether MV Log inserts behave the same as other transactions. Sounds like they do. And thanks for explaining phantom reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my above comments I would like to suggest modified approach. Create a new table say mv_log_replica. This table should be a replica of your mv_log table.

```
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM mv_log_replica;
   INSERT INTO mv_log_replica
   (
   pk_col,
   col1,
   col2)
   SELECT
   pk_col,
   col1,
   col2
   FROM mlog$_my_tab;

   /* Call externall process and pass the data */
   /* Here instead of mlog$_my_tab use the mv_log_replica table */

   DELETE FROM mlog$_my_tab a 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mv_log_replica b WHERE a.pk_col = b.pk_col);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

This approach will ensure that you are only deleting that data which is copied to the mv_log_replica table. If any additional data is inserted into the mv_log in between it will not be deleted. Further, you can make the mv_log_replica a global temporary table (ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS).

Comment: Yes. Or I can make it a permanent table to collect logs from multiple sources. Wondering if I can rely on ROWIDs instead of PKs. But I will open a new thread with that question.

Comment: There may be another alternative. I was able to add a column to the log with DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP.

Comment: Yes, going with timestamp would a better option.